# "Unresolvable dependency resolving" Error, Laravel Service Provider

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, package, laravel-5.1

I'm trying my hand at building a custom Service Provider package, however I'm running into the following error. Does anyone have experience with this?

`Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $app ]] in class Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider`

Package Folder Structure:

```
[root]
....packages/
........mbarwick83/
............previewr/
................src/
....................PreviewrServiceProvider.php
....................Previewr.php
................composer.json
```

config/app.php:

`Mbarwick83\Previewr\PreviewrServiceProvider::class`

Service Provider:

```
<?php

namespace Mbarwick83\Previewr;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class PreviewrServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Indicates if loading of the provider is deferred.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $defer = false;

    /**
     * Perform post-registration booting of services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Register any package services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('Mbarwick83\Previewr\Previewr',function($app){
            return new Previewr($app);
        });
    }
}
```

Previewr.php (class):

```
<?php

namespace Mbarwick83\Previewr;

class Previewr
{
    /**
     * Create a new Previewr Instance
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Friendly welcome
     *
     * @param string $phrase Phrase to return
     *
     * @return string Returns the phrase passed in
     */
    public function something($phrase)
    {
        return $phrase;
    }
}

Controller/view:

use Mbarwick83\Previewr\PreviewrServiceProvider as Previewr;

public function index(Previewr $previewr)
{
    echo $previewr->something('Hello, League!');
}
```

composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Mbarwick83\\Previewr\\": "packages/Mbarwick83/Previewr/src"
        }
    },
```

Comment: Did you try to use `composer dump-autoload` and `composer update`?

Comment: @aldrin27 Yeah, I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, are you sure you want to inject your service provider?

```
use Mbarwick83\Previewr\PreviewrServiceProvider as Previewr;
```

Chances are you want to use this instead:

```
use Mbarwick83\Previewr\Previewr;
```

Comment: Okay, that fixes it!! Question - what does this work (sorry, broad question)...but what is this doing?

Comment: Also, if I was going to use a `facade` for injection, i'd use `use Mbarwick83\Previewr\Facades\Previewr;` instead right (assuming I created the facade class of course.

Comment: You don't inject facades. If you're using injection there's no point in facades.

Comment: Facades are usually advised to Services that has "complicated classes" in its workings. So the facades will hide the complexity and expose the functionality in a simpler form for the client. Otherwise, the facade becomes added complexity itself.